# Installing with Wubi

Tags: installation, wubi

I want to give Ubuntu a try, but I don't have a disc or usb lying around so I decided to use the Wubi installer. If I erase the copy of Windows that I use to install Wubi, will I still be able to access Wubi?

Comment: Welcome buddy! I can see that you have a lot of doubts, so I recommend to go for the full installation. Beside, WUBI is not supported any more. *Get a DVD, ask for it to a friend, buy a USB stick, or something* that allow to you to do a complete installation of Ubuntu. More information: http://askubuntu.com/q/6328/62483

Answer (score 2):

The Wubi installation exists as normal files on one of your Windows partitions, so yes, if you do anything to delete the partition or erase all its contents, you will lose your Wubi install. Being ordinary files, though, you could back them up to another partition or external HD.